# Duplicate Zip entry Android after adding Sinch to the libs folder

Tags: android, scala, sinch

```
/libs/sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar:com/sinch/verification/Config.class])
```

*build.sbt*

> unmanagedJars in Compile += file("libs/sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar")

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Duplicate zip entry [sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar:com/sinch/verification/Config.class]


[error] (android:proguard) java.io.IOException: Can't write [/Users/******/target/android/intermediates/proguard/classes.proguard.jar] (Can't read [/Users/******/libs/sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/**,!rootdoc.txt)] (Duplicate zip entry [sinch-android-verification-1.1.2.jar:com/sinch/verification/Config.class]))
```

Comment: sorry for the formatting. Please ask in case any info is missing.

Comment: Do you get the same error in Android studio (What are you trying to do with Scala here?)

Comment: @cjensen I am using Scala Android for developing Android Apps. Here is the substitute of gradle android plugin I am using in my project https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin

Comment: I have no experience with the Scala enviroment, maybe its some setting in the gradle that doesnt convert since it says "standard android project" maybe you can see something here https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/android under Eclipse/IntelliJ settings

Comment: Also check the Proguard-project.txt file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line specifying:

```
unmanagedJars in Compile
```

is superfluous and the cause of this error.